# symfony not recognizing an authenticated user

Tags: authentication, symfony

I am trying to implement a login page with symfony2 and for that I am using my own custom user provider.

The problem is when the user enters his credentials, he will not be recognized. By that, I mean the debug bar at the bottom says "You are not authenticated." and `$request->getUser()` will return null. But the strange thing is that the user will still be allowed to visit the pages that need him to log in.

I don't think the problem is with the authentication, since when I enter a wrong password, I get warned about it, but when I enter the correct one, I get redirected to the first page (but it still says "You are not authenticated.")

Do you know where I should be looking for the problem?

I have attached my `security.yml` file in [this pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5710456/) and `routing.yml` in [this one](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5710459/).
[Here](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2454580) is the code for my custom user provider.
And [This](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/2454592) is the User class definition.

**EDIT**: Here is the var_dump of my `get('security.context')->getToken()`. The funny thing is that `authenticated` is true, but `getUser()` is still null and the debug bar says I am not authenticated.

```
object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken)#46 (6) {
  ["credentials":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":private]=>
  NULL
  ["providerKey":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":private]=>
  string(11) "system_area"
  ["user":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  NULL
  ["roles":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role)#45 (1) {
      ["role":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":private]=>
      string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role)#44 (1) {
      ["role":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":private]=>
      string(9) "ROLE_USER"
    }
  }
  ["authenticated":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. It was because of the dummy code I had used in place of serialization of User objects. I replaced it with real code and problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the current User you have to use:

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

In order to check if the current User has a certain role use:

```
 $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')
```

Comment: $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser() is null

Comment: have you checked that your session is started ? $this->get('session')->isStarted() ? Check your app/logs/dev.log if the user is loaded when loading the page.

Comment: Is the user loaded from database on request ? How does your authentication handler look ?

Comment: Yes, I take it from a database. The user provider gets the email from the login form, queries it from database, and returns the User object. (want the code?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30775/discussion-between-untitled-and-nifr)